# fiddler doesn't capture windows live writer traffic

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, http, fiddler, windows-live-writer

I have been trying to capture windows live writer traffic through fiddler for my application which runs on IIS Express but I am unable to.

Fiddler is open, capture traffic mode is on. I also used the following host:

> `http://localhost.fiddler:36669/`

What would I be missing here? I'm on Windows 8.1.

Comment: What "traffic" would Windows Live Writer be submitting to your IIS server? Is IIS running on your localhost? If so, you may need to remove the default proxy exception rule that tells programs to bypass the proxy if they are going in via localhost. If you're sure the protocol being used between your web server and Windows Live Writer is HTTP, HTTPS, SPDY or FTP, and not some other protocol (which Fiddler would never detect because it's not designed to), then you may need to restart IIS and/or Windows Live Writer after you turn on capture traffic, so that they detect the system proxy update.

Comment: @allquixotic :) yes, there are HTTP requests to my application which runs on locally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When WLW hits the target URL, it downloads an XML file containing information about your blog. Within that information, I'm guessing that you have a hardcoded URL to `//localhost` and that's a problem because the .NET Framework (used by WLW) will always bypass the proxy for that hostname. To fix it, you can probably change the URL in that file to be a relative URL (so that your `localhost.fiddler` trick takes effect) or the current machine's name.